# What is the fastest and safest way to stop looping thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a few background threads that are running in a loop, that sometimes call native Win32 functions using PInvoke. I need to be able to stop such thread from the main thread as fast as I can. I used to do thread.Abort method, which stops the thread pretty fast, but if a thread was somewhere in Win32 native function at the moment it receives ThreadAbort exception it sometimes results in "dangling" handles/pointers and memory leaks. What is the fastest and safest way to stop such thread? Thanks!

Comment: Not a duplicate because I need to kill a thread as fast as I can, I can't wait for it to check a flag in a loop, because one loop itteration takes a lot of time.

Comment: You ask for the "fastest and safest". The duplicate does some suggestions, some for the fastest and some for the safest. Pick the one that suits you best.

Comment: Fast is easy, but safe is not. There is no safe way to abort a thread.